# how to dispatch a action in redux middleware?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-middleware

I wrote a middleware, like as blow :

```
const testMiddleware = ({ dispatch, getState }) => next => action => {
    console.log('test middleware')
};

export default testMiddleware;
```

and added it to my store: `applyMiddleware(testMiddleware)` in ever action, i get `test middleware` in my console.

and i wrote a simple action, like this:

```
export const sayHi = () => {
    return dispatch => {
        console.log('hi');
    }
}
```

How can i dispatch `sayHi` action in my middleware?

Comment: Are you trying to create your own `thunk` or some custom middleware?

Comment: i want create custom middleware for myself, getState work but i can't dispatch a action.

Answer (score 3):

Middleware gets the store’s getState() and dispatch() functions as first argument, so you can do the following (after importing required  actions):

```
const middleware = ({dispatch, getState }) =>{
    return next => action => {
        dispatch(someAction);
        // return data;
        return next(action);
  }
}
```

> So, the middleware signature is ({ getState, dispatch }) => next => action.

https://redux.js.org/api/applymiddleware

Comment: what is `data` in `return data` ? i getting error `InternalError: too much recursion`

Comment: Of course you get an error cause data is undefined variable, that was just an example) you should return action as mentioned in the link

Comment: thank you, i wrote like your new answer, but i get error `InternalError: too much recursion` please check your chat.